# How to fix Entity Framework Core temporary table generating fields which are too small

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a EF Core solution which must import various data. Basically I generate a bunch of entities in my web service, and then tell the DB to save, but something strange happens in some cases.

Note that the following field "Value" has an nvarchar(max) in the final table, but EF Core generates a temporary table for inserting (taken from the profiler) which then fails:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @toInsert0 TABLE ([AttributeID] int, [ChangeLogCreated] int, [ChangeLogDeleted] int, [ChangeLogModified] int, [EntityID] int, 
[Value] nvarchar(450), [_Position] [int]);
INSERT INTO @toInsert0
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, 0),
(@p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10, @p11, 1);

DECLARE @inserted0 TABLE ([ValueID] int, [_Position] [int]);
MERGE [ToSIC_EAV_Values] USING @toInsert0 AS i ON 1=0
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT ([AttributeID], [ChangeLogCreated], [ChangeLogDeleted], [ChangeLogModified], [EntityID], [Value])
VALUES (i.[AttributeID], i.[ChangeLogCreated], i.[ChangeLogDeleted], i.[ChangeLogModified], i.[EntityID], i.[Value])
OUTPUT INSERTED.[ValueID], i._Position
INTO @inserted0;

SELECT [t].[ValueID] FROM [ToSIC_EAV_Values] t
INNER JOIN @inserted0 i ON ([t].[ValueID] = [i].[ValueID])
ORDER BY [i].[_Position];

',N'@p0 int,@p1 int,@p2 int,@p3 int,@p4 int,@p5 nvarchar(max) ,@p6 int,@p7 int,@p8 int,@p9 int,@p10 int,@p11 nvarchar(450)',@p0=5590,@p1=15355,@p2=NULL,@p3=NULL,@p4=20716,@p5=N'<p><em>You can&nbsp;quickly change / remove this text&nbsp;once you''ve figured out how to work with the tiles.&nbsp;</em></p>
<p>This simple&nbsp;app let''s&nbsp;you choose icons to create nice tiles. The initial output is&nbsp;optimized for&nbsp;bootstrap skins.&nbsp;Your next steps are probably:</p>
<ol>
<li>Edit / add tiles (hover over the tiles and use the toolbar like the <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>)</li>
<li>Write something else here or change the default look of <em>all</em> tiles in this group&nbsp;(just hover over this text and click <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> in the toolbar)</li>
<li>Change the appearence of one&nbsp;icon (<i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> then change the presentation-settings <i class="fa fa-toggle-off"></i> at the bottom of the form)</li>
<li>Modify the HTML template as you wish&nbsp;(click on the <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i> till you get <i class="fa fa-code"></i>)</li>
</ol>',@p6=5589,@p7=15355,@p8=NULL,@p9=NULL,@p10=20716,@p11=N'Content Tiles App'
```

As you can see, it generates a @toInsert0 table with a [Value] allowing only an nvarchar(450), and then later on says that @p5 is an nvarchar(max) - which then fails on insert.

My model is very simple and has no character restrictions - like this:

```
    ...
    public int ValueId { get; set; }
    public int EntityId { get; set; }
    public int AttributeId { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    ...
```

And in the DB Context there is also nothing special, just this:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<ToSicEavValues>(entity =>
        {
            ...
            entity.Property(e => e.Value).IsRequired();
            ...
```

So why does Entity Framework get the idea to create a temporary 450 character table as an intermediate format? how can I fix this?